# Confusion matrix in linear regression

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, confusion-matrix

I have actual values and predicted values.

Actual:
33.3663, 38.2561, 28.6362, 35.6252

Predicted:
28.9721, 35.6161, 27.9561, 22.6272

I want to apply confusion matrix to find the accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

First thing, confusion matrix is not for continuous values. AND you can also use it by converting continuous values to classes. check https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46019/continuous-variable-not-supported-in-confusion-matrix

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
 
expected = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
predicted = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
results = confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)
print(results)
```

### Output

```sh
[[4 2]
 [1 3]]
```

### Reference

https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/

Answer (score 1):

It is true that confusion matrix can not be applied directly on continuous data, but it is possible to do a categorization by ranges of your continuous data and then get the confusion matrix for values-ranges.